# AWK: replacing \' but not \\'

Tags: regex, awk, gsub

My string:

```
INSERT INTO tb(str) VALUES('So is there really more of you to love now? it\'s ...HB\\');
```

Now, I have to make it compatible for SQLite, so I have to replace single quotes to 2 single quotes. I tried this AWK script but, I want to replace only `\'` not `\\'`.

```
echo "So is there really more of you to love now? it\'s ...HB\\'" | awk '{ gsub( /\57\047/, "\047\047" ); print; }'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kent$  cat f
it\'s ...HB\\'

kent$  sed 's/\\\\\x27/\x99/g;s/\\\x27/&\x27/g;s/\x99/\\\\\x27/g' f
it\''s ...HB\\'
```

- `\x27` is single quote `'`
- `\x99` is invisible char
- first replace all `\\'` by `\x99`
- then replace all `\'` by `\\'`
- finally restore all `\x99` back to `\\'`
- done

If awk is required for some reaseon:

```
kent$  cat f
it\'s ...HB\\'

kent$  awk '{gsub(/\\\\\x27/,"\x99");gsub(/\\\x27/,"&\x27");gsub(/\x99/,"\\\\\x27")}7' f
it\''s ...HB\\'
```

Comment: if `\'` is not at start of line, can be simplified to `sed -E 's/([^\\])\\\x27/&\x27/g'` ... or use tool with lookarounds... `perl -pe 's/(?!<\\)\\\x27/$&\x27/g'`

Comment: I used gsub(/\\\\\x27/,"\x99\x0\x0\x99"); gsub(/\\\x27/,"\x27\x27"); gsub(/\x99\x0\x0\x99/,"\\\\\x27"); as \x99 was interfering with some unicode characters.

Comment: That's doubling the `'`s too. Also, don't use hex `\x27` to represent a `'`, use octal `\047` instead - see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Comment: @EdMorton thx for the `\x vs \0` suggestion. regarding to the `'` doubling, I think OP wants to double the `'` to make `\'` into `\''` `"so I have to replace single quotes to 2 single quotes."`

Comment: @Pradeep wrt your comment above, YMMV with putting nul characters inside strings since some awk implementations might be assuming C strings which cannot contain nul characters so what they'd do with that would be implementation dependent.

Comment: @Kent I assumed he wanted to double the escapes not the quotes. I now think in light of his comment that what he REALLY wants is to change `\'` to `''` (i.e. replace the backslash with a quote). Once again I got sucked into participating in a question with no sample input and expected output. When will I learn.... :-(

Answer (score 0):

alternative ***sed*** approach:

```
s="So is there really more of you to love now? it\'s ...HB\\'"
echo $s | sed "s/\([^\][\]\)'/\1''/g"
```

The output:

```
So is there really more of you to love now? it\''s ...HB\''
```

Comment: Sir, this wouldn't solve my problem for 2 reasons, one, I want it in AWK and second, \\' should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing @Kent's sample input file:

```
$ cat file
it\'s ...HB\\'
```

Your question is unclear since you didn't provide expected output but to double the escapes:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\\\\\047/,"\n"); gsub(/\n|\\\047/,"\\\\\047")} 1' file
it\\'s ...HB\\'
```

and to double the quotes:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\\\\\047/,"\n"); gsub(/\\\047/,"&\047"); gsub(/\n/,"\\\\\047")} 1' file
it\''s ...HB\\'
```

and to change `\'` to `''`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\\\\/,"\n"); gsub(/\\\047/,"\047\047"); gsub(/\n/,"\\\\")} 1' file
it''s ...HB\\'
```

That will work no matter what characters are present in your input file since it uses a newline as the temporary `\\'` replacement and a newline obviously can't be present in the line so you KNOW it's safe to use as the temp value.